# Reducing response time for Java EE web application

Tags: performance, profiling

Need a solution for reducing response time for a Java EE web application that uses portlets. I need to reduce the login to homepage timing. Can someone suggest me any tool that can help me identify slow backend database calls, bottlenecks
Also what report of that tool will help me get the
Method calls vs time taken data

Comment: Anyone please give me some starting..???????

Answer (score 1):

Well this is an old question but will try to give you an answer

Working with Java EE you can use interceptors and to create your own performance logging.

However if you want a tool you can use visualVM, JProbe or Jprofiler just to name a few.